# Parsing xml in sench touch 2

Tags: xml-parsing, sencha-touch-2

I want to parse an xml using sencha touch , i've tried all the possibilities in stckovrflow , but nothing's display :

XML DATA :
from : http://www.aufaitmaroc.com/feeds/maroc.xml

The store :

```
 Ext.define("MyApp2.store.NewsStore", {
 extend: "Ext.data.Store",
 requires: ["Ext.data.proxy.JsonP", "Ext.dataview.List", "MyApp2.model.News"           ,"Ext.data.reader.Xml"],
config: {
model: "MyApp2.model.News",
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'jsonp',
    url: 'http://www.aufaitmaroc.com/feeds/maroc.xml',
    reader: {
        type: 'xml',
        record: 'item',
        rootProperty: 'channel'
        }
    }
}    
});
```

My model :

```
Ext.define("MyApp2.model.News", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
config: {
type:'tree',
fields: [
{name: 'title', type: 'auto'}

 ]
  } 
   });
```

My view :

```
 {
                    xtype: "list",
                    store: "NewsStore",
                    itemTpl: '<h1>{title}</h1>'
 }
```

I've this errors in the console of chrome :

[image: Picture from my browser]

I've tried to resolve my problem :
I add this in my HTTPD.conf of apache (Im using WampServer)

```
    AddType application/x-font-woff .woff
    AddType application/rss+xml .xml
```

and i created : httpd-proxy.conf and put it in the extra folder

My httpd-proxy.conf

```
 ProxyRequests Off
 ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /EMBackend http://localhost:8383/MyApp2/index.html
ProxyPassReverse /EMBackend http://localhost:8383/MyApp2/index.html
<Location /EMBackend>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
 </Location>
```

I've add this to httpd.conf:

```
 Include conf/extra/httpd-proxy.conf
```

& stil can't display any data .Any help will be appreciated :)

Ps:I tried to use JsonP like that :

```
       proxy: {
    type: 'jsonp',
     url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?         v=1.0&q=http://www.aufaitmaroc.com/feeds/maroc.xml',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        rootProperty: 'responseData.feed.entries'
        }
    }
```

I dont get all data u can try on puting the url in your browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK JSONP will not work with xml. You will need to use a service like yql to convert the xml to json.
[This fiddle is demo of doing that](http://jsfiddle.net/blessenm/GsuEW/).

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Station', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            'title'
        ]
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.store.Stations', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: 'MyApp.model.Station',
    config: {
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'MyApp.model.Station',
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            //url    : 'http://www.aufaitmaroc.com/feeds/maroc.xml',
            url: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20rss%20where%20url%20%3D%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fnews.google.co.in%2Fnews%3Fpz%3D1%26cf%3Dall%26ned%3Din%26hl%3Den%26output%3Drss%22&format=json&diagnostics=true',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'query.results.item'
            }
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('MyApp.list.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        itemTpl: '{title}',
        store: Ext.create('MyApp.store.Stations')
    }
});

Ext.create('MyApp.list.List');
```

Using YQL,
Go to yql console page - http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/

Type in the following line in the YQL Statement box.
'select * from rss where url = "http://www.aufaitmaroc.com/feeds/maroc.xml"'

Select the json option in the radio button below

Clear the input box on the side of the radio button. It should be empty.

Uncheck both the 'diagnostic' and 'debug' checkbox.

Then press 'Test' button. This should give you the output below.

Now after all this, go to the bottom of the page. There should be the 'THE REST QUERY' section.
There is a url. Note that in the url there will be something like '&callback=' at the end of the url. Remove this, and use the remaining as the url for the store. The callback portion of the url is automatically handled by sencha.

Comment: Thank u for answering , but i'm new on js , i didt get how & where do i have to put my url (http://www.aufaitmaroc.com/feeds/maroc.xml) in order to be converted to json ?

Comment: One more question plz ,i'me trying to build an application of news, & have for each category an url ,so do i have to create for each category a store.js?or there is an other option ?

Comment: I think the store can be same, the only thing that changes is the url. So pass the url when you create the store isntance.

Comment: I create a file & put it in the store folder ,it contains the url ,i'm respecting the mvc architect , so i cant create the store within to wiew  , im just calling it using hos name ..

Comment: You might want to create another question with your new problem.

Comment: Its me again YQL doesn't work anymore , it gives me a null result 
{
 "query": {
  "count": 0,
  "created": "2013-05-30T10:26:21Z",
  "lang": "en-US",
  "results": null
 }
}
even if my xml is full :s

Comment: Might need to post on the YDN network. there service might be down

Comment: that's what i did , i'm waiting for answer :) thanks for ur concerne